# Debian Jessie is installing too many backports

Tags: debian, apt, backports

I have Debian Jessie and have added backports (according to [these instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)):

```
echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

(I did this to get a newer kernel, as I needed it, of for some hardware in my laptop.)

The instructions say that nothing should happen, unless I explicitly ask for a backported package. e.g. `apt-get -t jessie-backports install "package"`.

However I now seem to have a whole load of my system from backports, and one package has un-installed, because it depends on an exact version, of something that was updated to back-ports.

So my question:

- How do I first stop it, so that no more backports are installed?
- How do I remove the existing backports?

---

Note: this gets a list of installed packages that are from backports (and in format that can be passed to `apt-get install`, for some reason putting `sudo apt-get install` in place of echo at end of pipeline does not work ):

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log.1 |grep -v linux | grep -v xserver | grep -v firmware | grep "status installed" | grep bpo | cut -d" " -f 5 | cut -d: -f 1 | xargs -i{} -n1 bash -c "dpkg-query -s {} >/dev/null && echo {}" | sed -r -e "s~.*~\0/jessie~" | xargs echo
```

Caution:

Some of the packages are automatically installed, so if you reinstall them all, then these automatically installed packages will be marked as manually installed. Thus not removed when not needed.

Any one have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Try adding the following to either `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

   `APT::Default-Release "jessie";`
2. To remove the existing backports, you'll need to get a list of which ones were installed, and what version they replaced.  Fortunately, this information can be extracted very easily from `/var/log/dpkg.log`

e.g. `grep ' upgrade ' /var/log/dpkg.log` will give you many lines like the following:

```
2016-02-15 11:06:32 upgrade python-numpy:amd64 1:1.11.0~b2-1 1:1.11.0~b3-1
```

This says that at 11:06am on 15th Feb, I upgraded python-numpy from version 1:1.11.0~b2-1 to version 1:1.11.0~b3-1

If I wanted to downgrade to the previous version, then I would run:

```
apt-get install python-numpy=1:1.11.0~b2-1
```

NOTE: in this particular case, it probably won't work because I run debian `sid` aka `unstable` so the old version is probably no longer available in the deb repository.  If you're running `jessie` and are re-installing a jessie version of a package as a downgrade to the jessie-backports version, it will work as expected.

Similarly, if a package has been removed you can find it and its exact version by grepping for `remove` in `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

---

Bulk downgrading of many packages can be largely automated using standard tools like `awk` and `grep`.  For example, If you know that the jessie-backports upgrades you installed were all done on a particular day (e.g. 2016-02-15), then you can downgrade to the previous versions with something like:

```
 apt-get -d -u install $(awk '/2016-02-15 ..:..:.. upgrade / {print $4 "=" $5}'
    /var/log/dpkg.log)
```

(line-feed and indentation added to avoid horizontal scroll-bar)

NOTE the use of the `-d` (`--download-only`) option.  Re-run the command and remove that option after you've verified that the `apt-get install` will do what you want, and ONLY what you want.

I would also recommend running only the `awk` portion of that command by itself first so you can see a list of exactly which packages and versions will be re-installed.

Comment: by 'largely automated' I mean that while it will mostly work without problems, it doesn't/won't always run perfectly (depending on the exact packages involved and their depends/recommends/conflicts/etc lines).  There may be one or two packages you have to manually install or uninstall  with either `apt-get` or `dpkg`.  As long as you don't panic, there is nothing to worry about.  Most problems with packaging systems are caused by people panicking and reacting without thinking....take it slowly and think before you act.

Comment: Should not he pin the new kernel  packages to backports @cas?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt but it's not necessary, and pinning is quite a bit more complicated and difficult to get right than just setting the Apt::Default-Release.  `apt-get` won't downgrade an already installed package unless you explicitly tell it to.  And @richard said he wanted to install `jessie` packages by default unless he explicitly specified `jessie-backports` - i assume that wish applies to kernel packages too.

Comment: he said he included backports to have a new kernel, probably like me, to have kernel 4 in jessie.

Comment: Feel free to add another answer documenting how to pin kernel related packages to jessie-backports then.  It's not something I feel inclined to do since it wasn't required by the original question but if you post a good answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: I was double checking your opinion actually, I have been thinking about pinning it, but it has been working fine as you say. kernel installed by the backports upgrade from backports due to the "side-effect" of having versions greater than the normal repositories. Or so I think, will have to investigate it better. I am only using pinning to keep systemd out.

Comment: I guess that people who use `stable` + `stable-backports` probably care a lot more about pinning than I do and have put in the effort to learn more about it.  I tend to run `unstable` and keep my systems synced up the latest sid fairly regularly (with occasional extras from `experimental`), so have little need for pinning.  The only time I used it heavily was years ago during the transition to gnome3, when I didn't want my gnome2 packages being replaced - i remember that maintaining the constantly changing list of packages to pin was a PITA.  I've since switched to xfce and purged gnome.

Comment: I have discovered for apt-get manual that I can do `apt-get install «package»/jessie` instead of `apt-get install «package»=«version»`.

Comment: I produced a list of packages that are from backports, and then it occurred to me that some are automatically installed, so if I reinstall them all, then these automatically installed packages will be marked as manually installed. Any one have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me out. I hat to extend the 1st awk command by a 2nd piped awk to remove the arch-information seperated by a colon: `| awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $1 "=" $3}'`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have not properly setup `/etc/apt/preferences`.
The following will prevent anything from being installed from jessie-backports expect what tell it to install (such as the backported kernel).
You will still have issues if the specified packages require other packages from backports that are not listed.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 1000

# this will allow you to not have to use '-t jessie-backports install'
Package: linux-doc linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 linux-source
Pin: release n=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

If you wish to get a list of backported packages installed you can use the following script (or parts of it):

```
chmod a+x name_of_script ./name_of_script > name_of_output_file
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
RELEASES="jessie-backports"

echo  "Searching for installed packages from" >&2
echo $RELEASES | sed s/^/" * "/ | sed s/\|/"\n * "/g >&2

for package in $(dpkg -l | grep -i ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
do
check=$( apt-cache policy $package 2>&1 | grep -i -A 1 "[*]" | egrep $RELEASES )
if [ "$check" == "" ] ; then
 echo -ne "." >&2
else
 echo -ne "#" >&2
 echo
 apt-cache policy $package
fi
done
echo >&2
echo
```

If you want to downgrade any packages listed by the above script append the following to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: package1 package2 package3
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your pinning configuration for apt in /etc/apt/preferences and /etc/apt/preferences.d/

Is it possible you might have added a custom pinning configuration and forgotten about it? That's the only way I can think of that would make apt prefer backports as it seems to be doing to you. Otherwise, it's just pulling dependencies - which the packages you specified require.

Official backports are already pinned lower (100) than jessie in the backported packages Release file in the backports repo. You should not have to do any apt configuration to make apt prefer jessie over jessie-backports.