# Fuzzy display after system upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, gnome-shell

I'm getting a fuzzy image on my Ubuntu after the latest automatic system upgrade.

[image]

*(please ignore the reflections in the image, but a screenshot would not show the fuzziness).*

I think these may be relevant:

- X.Org X Server 1.17.2
- GNOME Shell 3.16.4
- Kernel 4.2.0-30-generic #36-Ubuntu

Running `sudo lshw -C display` outputs (trimmed):

```
*-display               
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    version: 09
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

My updates are set to `wily-security` and `wily-updates`.

I tried to update all three of them, but only the kernel had a new version. After installing it and rebooted, the problem persisted.
I also tried an `LXDM` and even `TTY` but both showed the same problem.
So i would remove `Gnome-shell` from the equation but...

I'm out of ideas. Any advice?

---

`BIOS` and `live ubuntu` are showing normal graphics, so i can rule-out a display failure.

Comment: what kind of video card is it?  AMD? Nvidia? Intel?  what model?   what kernel version (if any) and driver version did the upgrade install?  if AMD or nvidia, are you using the open source drivers (radeon or nouveau) or the proprietary drivers (fglrx or nvidia)?

Comment: @cas, added info. It's an Intel mobile 915.

Comment: Also, I don't know *what* it auto-updated. Is there an update log?

Comment: Try booting the old kernel, see if the issue persists.

Comment: @schaiba, I've tried all kernel versions (4.2.0-22, -23, -25 and -30). Same issue...

Comment: @AlexTartan - look in `/var/log/dpkg.log` that is a log of all installs, upgrades, uninstalls performed by `dpkg` (and all the tools that make use of `dpkg` like `apt-get` and `aptitude`).  btw you can find some tips on how to extract information from that log file and use it to downgrade certain packages at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263511/debian-jessie-is-installing-too-many-backports/263524#263524

Comment: @cas, Thank you! Looked through the dpkg log and I was able to find some *gtk2 upgrades. Ran a reinstall on them (and gnome-shell) and the glitch was gone! Please post your comment as an answer so i  can accept it! Note-to-self: always check the install log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/var/log/dpkg.log`, you can find a list of packages which have been installed, upgraded, or uninstalled by `dpkg` or any tools that make use of `dpkg`, such as `apt-get` and `aptitude`.

You can find some tips on how to extract that information from `dpkg.log` and use it to upgrade, downgrade, uninstall etc specific versions of specific packages at [Debian Jessie is installing too many backports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263511/debian-jessie-is-installing-too-many-backports/263524#263524)